# new line character in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, newline

I am currently writing a bash scipt where i need to concatenate the results within the output variable. However I need them to be seperated by newline charcater '\n' which does not seem to work... Any ideas ???

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "./"*
do

#echo "$i"
tmp=$('/home/eclipseWorkspace/groundtruthPointExtractor/Debug/groundtruthPointExtractor' "./"$i) 
#echo $Output
#printf "$i $Output\n">> output.txt
Output=$Output$(printf $'\n %s %s' "$i" "$tmp" )
done
echo $Output
echo $Output> output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well looks like

echo "$str" works

because when you print the string without quotes, newline are converted to spaces !!!

Comment: This is due to the value of the `IFS` variable. It is by default set to split words on whitespace characters, which includes the newline character. Using quotation marks prevents word splitting.

Comment: This behaviour is documented in the bash manual here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting

Answer (score 2):

You can skip accumulating the output in a single parameter with

```
DIR=/home/eclipseWorkspace/groundtruthPointExtractor/Debug
for i in *; do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$i" "$("$DIR/groundtruthPointExtractor" "$i")"
done | tee output.txt
```

The `printf` outputs the file name and the program output on one line. The aggregated output of all runs within the for-loop is piped to `tee`, which writes the output to both the named file and standard output.

Answer (score 0):

`echo` does not interpret backslash characters (like \n) by default. Use:

```
echo -e $Output


-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes
```

Comment: `-e` is not relevant here. Use double-quotes: `echo "$Output"`.

Comment: Without quotes, the shell will perform word splitting on the variable's value **before** invoking echo.